# How to tell AutoMapper to use "pass by reference?"

Tags: c#, automapper

By default automapper creates a new object based on the destination's type:

```
public void Doit( Person personMissingStuff )
{
    PersonTemplate template = _personDao.GetPersonTemplate(1);
    Mapper.CreateMap<PersonTemplate, Person>();
    Person basePerson = Mapper.Map<Person>( template );
    Mapper.CreateMap<Person, Person>();
    Person completePerson = 
       Mapper.Map<Person, Person>( basePerson, personMissingStuff );
    ...
}
```

Instead of getting a `completePerson` I just get a `basePerson` again.  How do I tell AutoMapper to run the mappings by reference instead of by value?

Comment: Should you actually be looking at `personMissingStuff` as the result of the merge? (I would have expected the method taking a destination instance to be `void` if that's the case, but you never know)

Comment: Is all the stuff you are missing from "personMissingStuff" pass by reference?  Is there Value objects that are getting passed correctly?

Comment: @O.O Does `basePerson` have properties with null values that are overwriting the equivalent non-null properties on `personMissingStuff`, and this is what you are seeing as the result in completedPerson?

Answer (score 0):

`Mapper.Map(source, dest)` actually returns the destination object, in your case it'll be `personMissingStuff`.

With that said, assuming that you want to fill in only the null properties in the destination, you need to configure the mapping properly, and not map when the destination property has value.

The following sample does exactly this for class properties. For value properties, probably you need to do additional configuration. The example uses NUnit and SharpTestsEx:

```
[TestFixture]
public class LoadIntoInstance
{
    public class Template
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string OtherData { get; set; }
    }        

    [Test]
    public void Should_load_into_instance()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Template, Person>()
            .ForMember(d=>d.OtherData, opt=>opt.Ignore());
        Mapper.CreateMap<Person, Person>()
            .ForAllMembers(opt=>opt.Condition(ctx=>ctx.DestinationValue==null));
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        var template = new Template {Name = "template"};
        var basePerson = Mapper.Map<Person>(template);

        var noNamePerson = new Person {OtherData = "other"};

        var result = Mapper.Map(basePerson, noNamePerson);

        result.Should().Be.SameInstanceAs(noNamePerson);
        result.Satisfy(r =>
                       r.Name == "template" &&
                       r.OtherData == "other");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use traditional shallow cloning...

```
Person completePerson = basePerson.MemberwiseClone();
```

This should keep the reference types and clone the value types.

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx)

Comment: It looks like the OP is trying to map to an existing instance, not create a clone (I'm not the downvoter btw)

Comment: Automapper does all kinds of other things in it's mapping besides copying data that he could be leveraging, this is not a complete solution to the OP's question.

Comment: I disagree, however maybe the OP can clarify.

Comment: Mm I want to end up with an object that is the "merge" of two objects, not a clone of one object, if that makes sense?

Comment: Well in this case, the reference types contained within Person would be "merged" as in pointing to the same reference field/property from each of them.

Comment: Ok, he could use the memberwise clone as a partial solution to get the byreference members, and use automapper to get the rest from the template, in that case though, he would most likely be cloning "personMissingStuff"